# Android - setVisibility not changing visibility of RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, android-studio, onclicklistener, android-view

I am trying to manipulate the visibility of `RelativeLayout` on a certain click event, using the `visibility` attribute.

After adding event handlers to each list item, I can check that the visibility status is changing, but in the Android emulator, the screen doesn't change at all (and I have tested it with visibility="visible" in the XML to make sure that it would show up).

Here's the code for the click handler:

```
someHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LayoutInflater layoutSeed = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View baseView = layoutSeed.inflate(R.layout.activity_listings, null, false);
            RelativeLayout popup = (RelativeLayout) baseView.findViewById(R.id.popupContainer);
            Log.d("Tag1",Integer.toString(popup.getVisibility()));
            popup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Log.d("Tag2",Integer.toString(popup.getVisibility()));
        }
});
```

Logcat shows the status change. I've also tried to `invalidate()` and `postInvalidate()` on both baseView and popup, as well as `popup.bringToFront()` and the combinations of these and so far nothing's working.

Any suggestions or possible routes to investigate?

Answer (score 6):

If the RelativeLayout you are trying to change visibility is already in the screen, you don't need to inflate it again. Please make a reference to already inflated one and change its visibility

```
holder.relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 2):

Gone will remove the view from your layout. Use **Invisible** instead of gone.

Answer (score 1):

when you click on button your View is replace by button's `OnClick(View v)` method.
so you just write down

```
v.popup(View.GONE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line of code:

```
View baseView = layoutSeed.inflate(R.layout.activity_listings, null, false);
RelativeLayout popup = (RelativeLayout) baseView.findViewById(R.id.popupContainer);
Log.d("Tag1",Integer.toString(popup.getVisibility()));
```

Actually, you're trying to create a new `baseView` and set it `gone`. If you want to set the row item `gone`, you should remove it from your adapter temporary instead such as (if you set itemView to gone, you should be careful with the resuing `view` of the adapter):

```
removeItemAt(getAdapterPosition()) 
notifyDataRemoved(getAdapterPosition())
```